# Send data from one controller to a different controller in different ng-app

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller 'searchCntr' with ng-app = 'homePage'. I want to send data using rootscope to a controller  = "HashPageCntr" with ng-app set as 'HashPage'. Can i do this using rootscope? I am new to this. Thanks in advance

```
var app =  angular.module('homePage',[]);

app.controller('searchCntr',function($scope,$http,$rootScope) {

$scope.searchHash =function () {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "search": $scope.search
        },
        url: "/fetchHashes"
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('eventName',data);
        window.location.assign("/goTohashPage");
    });
}
```

});

// This is a different controller.

```
var app =  angular.module('hashPage',[]);
app.controller('HashPageCntr',function($rootScope){

$rootScope.$on('eventName',function(event,data){
   alert("In hash Page ");
    alert(data);
});
```

});

Comment: Here you can find the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301554/is-it-possible-to-share-data-between-two-angularjs-apps

Comment: The problem is when i broadcast, i use window.location.assign(). It is not accessible in 'HashPageCntr'