# How to Pass Data in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

firstapp

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("welcome.htm").then(function (response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
});
});
```

sencond app

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp2', []);
app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("fsd.htm").then(function (response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
});
});
```

How to Pass data from one app to another app in angularjs ?

Comment: can you please send some examples@DhavalMarthak

Comment: @selvakumar why do you need two apps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to share data between two angularjs apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301554/is-it-possible-to-share-data-between-two-angularjs-apps)

Comment: let me try bro @AlekseySolovey

Comment: i need to pass data in different javascript@AlekseySolovey

Comment: how to use session in angularjs will this help me

Comment: This question should be closed as duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301554/is-it-possible-to-share-data-between-two-angularjs-apps

Comment: @selvakumar can you inject one module into another: `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp2']);` ? There shouldn't be any reason for you to have multiple apps

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared service to communicate between two angular apps.
However using multiple apps is not a good practice unless it is the only option left.

```
angular.module('sharedService', []).factory('SharedService', function() {
  var SharedService;
  SharedService = (function() {
    function SharedService() {}
    SharedService.prototype.setData = function(name, data) {};
    return SharedService;
})();
  if (typeof(window.angularSS) === 'undefined' || window.angularSS === null) {
    window.angularSS = new SharedService();
  }
  return window.angularSS;});
  angular.module("angularApp1", ['sharedService'])
    /*code */
  angular.module("angularApp2", ['sharedService'])
    /*code */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Create function like this in Service Lyaer
        editTool: function(yourData) {
                        var basicAuth = YOurauthenticateFuntion;
                        var url =  'url';
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http.post(url, yourData, {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Authorization': basicAuth 
                            }
                        }).then(function(data) {
                            if(data.status == 200) {
                            deferred.resolve(data.data);
                            } else {
                                deferred.reject(data);
                            }
                        }, function(error) {
                            deferred.reject(error);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
    and then can call in any controller using factory name.. that you have created for serviceCalls
```

Comment: [don't use `$q` and `$http` together](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/%24q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/), `$http` already returns a promise that can resolve your response / data